# Restrict Custom Field Value Responses for Contacts

Tags: clio-api

When sending a GET query for matters, you can use the `custom_field_ids[]` key with a custom field id as the value to pull down the fields for a specific custom field assigned to a matter.

The documentation shows no similar functionality for the contact object. I'm having to pull all `custom_field_values{field_name,value}` and parse this result to find the specific custom field value I'm looking for, when I'm querying a contact.

Is there a better way to get the custom field value for a specific custom field id for contacts than what I'm doing above? If not, I'd love to see the `custom_field_ids[]` parameter applied to the contact object.

Comment: As of today, it looks like the documentation includes a `custom_field_ids[]` query parameter for contact entities. It looks like this might have been addressed?

Comment: Hey Jacob, trying to retrieve contacts from Clio also and need to filter by phone_numbers or primary_phone_number but not sure if I should be using custom_field_values or query parameter; tried both but can't figure out what the syntax should look like.  Would u mind providing an example of what the query string should look like for this scenario?